# How to receive a new email directly from email server in Perl

Tags: perl, imap, pop3, email-client

I have a an application sitting on a desktop and I want to run it directly through the trigger of an Email. Basically I want a script that would periodically fetch new mails from the server and trigger my script on receipt of a specific mail.
How should I proceed, or in other words which libraries in Perl can help?

I have gone through POP and IMAP manuals…I just don't know a library in Perl that could help me listen to a server.

Comment: @MikePennington ... Just Edited

Comment: I am not looking for a solution..only the right libraries or packages that I can go through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Net::POP3](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/POP3.html) is a good place to start... this is an example from their manpage...

```
use Net::POP3;
$pop = Net::POP3->new('pop3host');
$pop = Net::POP3->new('pop3host', Timeout => 60);
if ($pop->login($username, $password) > 0) {
    my $msgnums = $pop->list; # hashref of msgnum => size
    foreach my $msgnum (keys %$msgnums) {
        my $msg = $pop->get($msgnum);
        print @$msg;
        $pop->delete($msgnum);
    }
}
$pop->quit;
```

Comment: @MikePennington...
When I try creating an object $pop....Perl gives it undefined value
I have installed the Net::POP3 module
Any reason for this behaviour

Comment: @Dilletante how did you install Net::POP3? Were there any failing tests?

Comment: @Dilletante, you need to use your mailserver's hostname instead of 'pop3host'.